# How can i make my iteration Macro skip some rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro, written in VBA that copies data from a sheet to another. Right now, the rows between 72 and 77 are not needed anymore(there's a table that is always positioned between those rows that needs to go), so i wanted to stop iterating on them, by removing them from the final sheet. How could i achieve this? Here's the code of my subroutine:

```
Windows(report).Activate
Sheets("bond forward").Select

k = 1000

For conta = 16 To 500
    If Cells(conta, 14) = "BDCHFT_MM" Then
        Rows(conta).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Rows(k).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next conta

k = 2000
For conta2 = 16 To 500
    If Cells(conta2, 14) = "BAT_TIGO" Then
        Rows(conta2).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Rows(k).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next conta2
```

Answer (score 1):

Even thought you are saying your code is copying from one sheet to another, I can't find the other sheet, you are copying from the same sheet some rows below.

Anyhow, I've amended your code so it won't be using `.Select` or `.Activate` which you should avoid. Also added a reference to the worksheet so you can always refere to it on your code like the example.

Something importan, use `Option Explicit` to force declare all your variables, or else you would face many errors:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, k As Long, l As Long, conta As Long

    'I believe the workbook with the bond forward sheet is not called report, so change the name and include it's extension
    Set ws = Workbooks("Report.xlsx").Sheets("bond forward")

    k = 1000
    l = 2000
    With ws
        For conta = 16 To 500
            If conta > 71 And conta < 78 Then GoTo NextRow 'this will skip the rows 72-77
            If .Cells(conta, 14) = "BDCHFT_MM" Then
                .Rows(conta).Copy 'you can copy in one step without selecting
                .Rows(k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False 'same for paste
                k = k + 1
            ElseIf .Cells(conta, 14) = "BAT_TIGO" Then 'also you don't need another loop to do this, just another variable for the paste row
                .Rows(conta).Copy
                .Rows(l).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                l = l + 1
            End If
NextRow:
        Next conta
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to skip loop is to write appropriate flag with `GoTo` statement:

```
Dim firstRowToSkip As Long, lastRowToSkip As Long
firstRowToSkip = 72
lastRowToSkip = 77
For conta = 16 To 500
    ' skip loop
    If conta >= firstRowToSkip And conta <= lastRowToSkip Then GoTo NextIteration
    'rest of loop
NextIteration:
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim k1 As Long, k2 As Long, conta As Long

    k1 = 1000
    k2 = 2000

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("bond forward")

        For conta = 16 To 500

            If conta > 72 And conta < 77 Then

                If .Cells(conta, 14) = "BDCHFT_MM" Then

                    .Rows(conta).Copy
                    .Rows(k1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    k1 = k1 + 1

                ElseIf Cells(conta, 14) = "BAT_TIGO" Then

                    .Rows(conta).Copy
                    .Rows(k2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    k2 = k2 + 1

                End If

            End If

        Next conta

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is gonna paste every row copied on row 1000 or row 2000. You are rebooting the `k1` and `k2` variables in every iteration.

Comment: The exclusion logic is wrong: it's actually including the rows 73 to 76 (which is the wrong range anyway), not excluding it. This needs rewriting a lot.